# Using audiofiles in a .jar file

Tags: java, audio

I made a program that plays .wav files when a certain event occurs. My problem is that once I export it to a .jar file, I don't think that the audio will still be available, because the path even fails when i move the file to another folder. How can I make it so that the exported jar can be downloaded by other people for example, and the sound will still play. Here's the code I'm using to play the sound:

```
    package one;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;

import sun.audio.*;

/**
 * A simple Java sound file example (i.e., Java code to play a sound file)
 */
public class Sound extends Thread
{
  public void play(String address) 
  throws Exception
  {
    // open the sound file as a Java input stream
    String soundfile = address;
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(soundfile);

    // create an audiostream from the inputstream
    AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(in);



      // play the audio clip with the audioplayer class
        AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);

  }

}
```

I create an object of this class in another class and feed it the link to the file:

```
try {
    sound = new Sound();
    sound.play("/Users/ekurt/Documents/coding/projects or exercise/Java Files/Ultimate Study Timer/study.wav");
} catch (Exception e1) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Edit:
I tried this

```
   sound = new Sound();
   InputStream i = TimerField.class.getResourceAsStream("/Users/ekurt/Documents/coding/projects or exercise/Java Files/Ultimate Study Timer/untitled.wav");
  sound.play(i);
```

I modified the Sound class to take an InputStream instead.

```
  public void play(InputStream address) 


     throws Exception
      {
        // open the sound file as a Java input stream
      //  String soundfile = address;
      //  InputStream in = new FileInputStream(soundfile);

        // create an audiostream from the inputstream
        AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(address);

        // play the audio clip with the audioplayer class
        AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
      }
```

And I don't know where the audio file is in the jar. I used the export function in eclipse and exported as a runnable jar.

Edit 2:

I'm going to attempt to clarify my question a bit. I'm currently running the program in eclipse. I know that the code I'm using right now won't work if the sound file is somewhere else. My question/issue is if I export as a jar, I think that if i sent it to someone else, that person wouldn't be able to run the code, because the string that gives the file location only works with the sound file in the correct folder.

So how do I make it so the sound file is packaged in the jar and the code can play the sound anywhere?

Comment: Load the file from class path.

Comment: Objects in a jar are not files so you cannot use `FileInputStream` to access them. Look at `Class.getResourceAsStream`

Comment: can you give me an example on how to use Class.getResourceAsStream. I just tried it and I must be doing it wrong

Comment: @zyzz no. Edit your question, show the code you tried, and tell us where the audio file is located in the jar file.

Comment: A jar file is a zip file. Use it with any zip utility. Or simply with `jar tvf thefile.jar`. Have you actually read the javadoc of getResource[AsStream()]? Don't you realize you need to pass the path of the file in the jar, and not the path of the file on your hard disk, since you want to read from the jar file?

Comment: I don't think you understand my question. I currently testing the code in eclipse. My issue is that I don't know how to make it play the sound even when the file is no longer in the same folder. I'm assuming i package it into the jar with the program. But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: So, you don't even know if the audio file is in the jar? Well, look into the jar and see if it's there. `jar tvf thefile.jar`. The eclipse wizard used to create the jar let's you choose what you put in the jar.

Comment: I just checked. The file doesn't seem to be in the jar. I also just went through the .jar export wizard in eclipse again. I can't seem to find the option to add the sound files.